# Problem getting height from div after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, height

I'm having a problem getting height from a div which is being filled by an ajax request. Consider following code

```
(function($) {
 $.fn.flickr = function(o){
 var s = {
api_key: '',              // [string]    required, see http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html
type: null,                 // [string]    allowed values: 'photoset', 'search', default: 'flickr.photos.getRecent'
photoset_id: null,          // [string]    required, for type=='photoset'  
text: null,                     // [string]    for type=='search' free text search
user_id: null,              // [string]    for type=='search' search by user id
group_id: null,             // [string]    for type=='search' search by group id
tags: null,                 // [string]    for type=='search' comma separated list
tag_mode: 'any',            // [string]    for type=='search' allowed values: 'any' (OR), 'all' (AND)
sort: 'date-posted-asc',    // [string]    for type=='search' allowed values: 'date-posted-asc', 'date-posted-desc', 'date-taken-asc', 'date-taken-desc', 'interestingness-desc', 'interestingness-asc', 'relevance'
thumb_size: 's',            // [string]    allowed values: 's' (75x75), 't' (100x?), 'm' (240x?)
size: 'o',                 // [string]    allowed values: 'm' (240x?), 'b' (1024x?), 'o' (original), default: (500x?)
per_page: 100,              // [integer]   allowed values: max of 500
page: 1,                      // [integer]   see paging notes
attr: '',                   // [string]    optional, attributes applied to thumbnail <a> tag
api_url: null,              // [string]    optional, custom url that returns flickr JSON or JSON-P 'photos' or 'photoset'
params: '',                 // [string]    optional, custom arguments, see http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html
api_callback: '?',          // [string]    optional, custom callback in flickr JSON-P response
callback: null              // [function]  optional, callback function applied to entire        <ul>
 };
 if(o) $.extend(s, o);
 return this.each(function(){
 // create unordered list to contain flickr images
     var list = $('<ul>').appendTo(this);
   var url = $.flickr.format(s);
    $.getJSON(url, function(r){
  if (r.stat != "ok"){
    for (i in r){
        $('<li>').text(i+': '+ r[i]).appendTo(list);
    };
  } else {
    if (s.type == 'photoset') r.photos = r.photoset;
    // add hooks to access paging data
    list.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+r.photos.page+'" />');
    list.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+r.photos.pages+'" />');
    list.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+r.photos.perpage+'" />');
    list.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+r.photos.total+'" />');
    for (var i=0; i<r.photos.photo.length; i++){
      var photo = r.photos.photo[i];
      // format thumbnail url
      var t = 'http://farm'+photo['farm']+'.static.flickr.com/'+photo['server']+'/'+photo['id']+'_'+photo['secret']+'_'+s.thumb_size+'.jpg';
      //format image url
      var h = 'http://farm'+photo['farm']+'.static.flickr.com/'+photo['server']+'/'+photo['id']+'_';
      switch (s.size){
        case 'm':
          h += photo['secret'] + '_m.jpg';
          break;
        case 'b':
          h += photo['secret'] + '_b.jpg';
          break;
        case 'o':
          if (photo['originalsecret'] && photo['originalformat']) {
            h += photo['originalsecret'] + '_o.' + photo['originalformat'];
            break;
          };
        default:
          h += photo['secret'] + '.jpg';
      };
      list.append('<li><a href="'+h+'" '+s.attr+' rel="photographs"><img src="'+t+'" alt="'+photo['title']+'" /></a></li>');
    };
    if (s.callback) s.callback(list);

        $('#photographs ul li a img').fadeTo('fast', 0.7);

        $('#photographs ul li a img').hover(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
            },function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
        });

        $("#photographs ul li a").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'zoomSpeedIn':      0, 
            'zoomSpeedOut': 0, 
            'overlayShow':      true,
            'overlayColor': '#000',
            'overlayOpacity': 0.9,
            'padding': 0
        });




           var outer = $('#photographs').outerHeight(),
           inner = $('#test').height();


           if(inner>outer){
               alert('Inner exceeded outer');
           }






      };
    });
});
};
```

At the very end, all my code in the callback is working on the ajax added images itself. I need to calculate the height of the inner div but i always get '0' because the images haven't been added yet. How do it do that?

Thank you very much if anyone can help me!

Mathijs

Answer (score 0):

windlow.load will ensure all the images are loaded

```
$(window).load(function(){
//initialize after images are loaded
});
```

this link explains even furthur on this

http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/

Comment: Hm, if i wrap that code between the window.load function, the `if(outer>inner){
      alert('Inner exceeded outer');
 }`

doesn't even work anymore (mind the 'outer>inner', not 'inner>outer', which makes sense).

Comment: @Mathijs ,is it , I used to have problem similar to that and when i changed to window.load it fixed the problem, but let read go through your code more and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, the width and height of the images will not be known to the browser until they are loaded (unless they are set manually).

You can use the 'onload' event of an Image object as a trigger to read the height and width properties.

Regarding the height of the div, try reading its height and width via [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) *after* the images are loaded. Again, you can use the onload event as a trigger.

Because you are adding the images as markup rather than objects, you may need to change your approach. For example, you could track image loads in an object:

```
var imageLoaded = {}; // Define above the loop
```

Then as you are iterating your photo collection you could do this:

```
imageLoaded[t] = false;
var imgObject = new Image;
img.onload = function () {
  imageLoaded[this.src] = true;
  for (key in imageLoaded) {
    if (!imageLoaded[key]) {
      return;
    }
    // All images are loaded if we get here.
    // So, call the function that requires all
    // images to be loaded first.
  }
}
img.src = t;
```

I forget what the jQuery idiom is for appending a child element, but where you are assembling the 'li', 'a' and 'img' as a string of markup, you could split it up into separate statements in order to handle the img element as an object.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem as well, I think the best way without needing to do complicated javascript hacks is to just specify the image widths and heights in the image tags.